# How to not allow someone else to delete access file in the share folder?

Tags: ms-access, vba, code-access-security

The small company in which I work have 4 desktops, and we have a shared folder. And we have one important access file which keeps updating. And I to set a password to open it or to delete it. Can I do that? if so please help me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is really a file permissions issue, not an Access issue.

1. First, right-click on the file and choose Properties. You should be presented with a dialog box with several tabs. One of the tabs will be named Security.

If you do not see a Security tab, you may have to disable simple file sharing. You can read my previous post on how to turn off simple file sharing in order to set permissions on individual files and folders.

2. Next, click the Advanced button at the bottom of the security tab.
3. Now uncheck the “Inherit from parent the permission entries that apply to child objects” box.

A new dialog will pop up asking if you want to copy or remove the parent permissions. Go ahead and choose Copy, as this will allow us to work with the current permissions and modify them to our liking. In newer versions of Windows 7, the option has changed to Add.

4. Now in the Permission Entries list box, you should remove any user or group that you do not want to have access to the file. If you want users to be able to read the file, modify the file, but simply not delete the file, click the user and click on Edit.
5. On the dialog box that pops up, you can now control each individual permission for that file or folder. This includes Traverse Folder, Create Files, Delete, Read Permissions, Change Permissions, etc.
6. Note that you can uncheck certain items from the Allow column and it will prevent the user from reading or modifying the file. However, even if you uncheck the Delete permission, the user will still be able to delete the file.

The only way to prevent file deletion is to not give read permissions and explicitly deny Delete permission. That means you can simply uncheck read permissions in the Allow column and check the Deny box for Delete. Unfortunately, once you give read permissions to a file, the user will be able to delete it.